Esay way to draw an image with TikZ
I want to draw this image:

I write this code:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[inner sep=0pt] (Q1) at (-3, 0) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (Q2) at (4, 0) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (Q3) at (-3, -1.5) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (Q4) at (4, -1.5) {};

\draw[<->, ultra thick] (Q1) node[left]{$d_1$} -- (Q2);
\draw[<->, ultra thick] (Q3) node[left]{$d_2$} -- (Q4);
\node[inner sep=0pt, label={[inner sep=5pt]below:{$L$}}] (L) at (-1, -3) {};
    \fill[black] (L) circle[radius=2pt];
\def\e{3*1.1917535926 - 3};
\def\f{2*2.7474774195 - 3};
\node[inner sep=0pt, label={[inner sep=5pt]below:{}}] (A) at (-3, \f) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt, label={[inner sep=5pt]below:{}}] (B) at (2, \e) {};
\draw [->, ultra thick] (L) -- ($(L)!0.85!(A)$) node[above]{$e_1$};
\draw [->, ultra thick] (L) -- ($(L)!1.3!(B)$) node[above]{$e_2$};
\path[->>, tips, thick] (Q1) -- +(right:2.5);
\path[->>, tips, thick] (Q3) -- +(right:2.5);

\node[red,scale=3] (I) at (intersection of  Q1--Q2 and L--B){.};
\node[red,scale=3] (J) at (intersection of  Q3--Q4 and L--A){.};
\node[red,scale=3] (K) at (intersection of  Q3--Q4 and L--B){.};
    
\pic[inner sep=2pt, above left, "$\ang{130}$", draw=black, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=0.4cm] {angle=B--I--Q1};
\pic[inner sep=2pt, above left, "$\ang{70}$", draw=black, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=0.4cm] {angle=A--J--Q3};
\pic[inner sep=2pt, below right, "$b$", draw=black, -, angle eccentricity=0.9, angle radius=0.2cm] {angle=L--J--Q4};
\pic[inner sep=2pt, above, "$c$", draw=black, -, angle eccentricity=0.9, angle radius=0.2cm] {angle=B--L--A};
\pic[inner sep=4pt, below left, "$a$", draw=black, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=0.2cm] {angle=Q3--K--L};
\pic[inner sep=2pt, above, "$f$", draw=black, -, angle eccentricity=0.9, angle radius=0.3cm] {angle=B--K--Q3};

%south east
%north west

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Is there any easier way to draw that?

Though you could do it with plain Tikz, the euclide encapsulation may be „easier“ : https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/tkz-euclide/info

Please choose a title which describes the actual problem you face so that future users with the same problem will be able to find it.

Edit:
What is more easy way to draw of your image is very opinion based. I would draw it on a bit different way: first I would define styles of images elements than compose the image. On this way the image code is (to my opinion) shorter and simpler:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,
                calc,
                decorations.markings,
                intersections,
                quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         > = Straight Barb,
alr/.style = {thick, <->},
arr/.style = {thick, ->},
  C/.style = {circle, draw=#1, fill=#1, inner sep=1.2pt},
  C/.default = red,
decoration = {markings,% switch on markings
              mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>>}}
              },
 MA/.style = {draw, angle eccentricity=1, angle radius=#1,
              inner sep=1pt},
 MA/.default = 3.3mm
                        ]

\coordinate[label=left:$d_1$] (Q1) at (-3, 0);
\coordinate                   (Q2) at ( 4, 0);
\coordinate[label=left:$d_2$] (Q3) at (-3,-1.5);
\coordinate                   (Q4) at ( 4,-1.5);
    \draw[alr]  (Q1) -- (Q2);
    \draw[alr]  (Q3) -- (Q4);
\node[C=black,label=below:$L$] (L) at (-1,-3) {};
\draw [arr] (L) -- (135:3) coordinate[label=$e_1$] (A);
\draw [arr] (L) -- ( 45:3) coordinate[label=$e_2$] (B);

\node    (H) at (intersection of  Q1--Q2 and L--A) {};
\node[C] (I) at (intersection of  Q1--Q2 and L--B) {};
\node[C] (J) at (intersection of  Q3--Q4 and L--A) {};
\node[C] (K) at (intersection of  Q3--Q4 and L--B) {};
    \path[decorate] (H) -- (I);
    \path[decorate] (J) -- (K);
    
\pic[MA, above  left, "$\ang{130}$"] {angle=B--I--Q1};
\pic[MA, above  left, "$\ang{70}$"]  {angle=A--J--Q3};
\pic[MA, below right, "$b$"]    {angle=L--J--Q4};
\pic[MA=2.4mm, above,   "$c$"]    {angle=B--L--A};
\pic[MA=2.4mm, below left, "$a$"]     {angle=Q3--K--L};
\pic[MA, above, "$f$"] {angle=B--K--Q3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

As you can see, I took a liberty and a wee bit change image style that it become more appealing (again, according to my opinion).

